# Remove www subdomain in nginx and puma config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, puma

I'm using puma and nginx to run a rails 3.2 app on AWS. I terminate my HTTPS on the loadbalancer (ELB). How can I redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com? My config below does not work.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    keepalive_timeout   65;
    keepalive_requests 200;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    upstream myapp {
        # Path to Puma SOCK file
        server unix:/var/www/nginx-default/myapp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name www.my-app.com;
        return 301  $scheme://my-app.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  my-app.com;
        root         /var/www/nginx-default/myapp/public;

        #charset koi8-r;

        # set client body size (upload size)
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://myapp; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid    30s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors   on;
    }

}
```

If I remove

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.my-app.com;
    return 301  $scheme://my-app.com$request_uri;
}
```

and use

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /var/www/nginx-default/myapp/public;

    #...
}
```

it works but does not handle the www subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

This is a speculative answer, as I do not use AWS and ELB. However, using `$scheme` in your redirect will result in HTTPS being redirected to HTTP:

If you do not accept HTTP at the ELB, you should redirect to HTTPS only, with:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.my-app.com;
    return 301  https://my-app.com$request_uri;
}
```

However, if you accept either HTTP or HTTPS at the ELB, you should be able to use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header inserted by the ELB. Try this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.my-app.com;
    return 301  $http_x_forwarded_proto://my-app.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I tried both. Still doesn't work. Our ELB can take both http and https but we redirect them all to https using rails.